# Segmentation Error

Tags: c++, c-strings

I am trying to implement my own shell in Linux. I take input from the user and parse it. But it gives segmentation error while I copy my tokens in a array. I am unable to solve this issue.

Here is the code I implemented

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char * input;
    string insert;
    cout<<"My Shell $";

    getline(cin,insert);
    input= new char [insert.size()+1];
    strcpy(input, insert.c_str());


    char * token;
    char * parsed[100];
    int count;

    token=strtok(input, " ");
    while (token!=NULL)
    {
        strcpy(parsed[count],&(token[count]));
        count++;
        token=strtok(NULL, " ");
    }


}
```

Comment: Some tips: 1) use C++ functions on `string`s instead of C functions on `char *`s. You should almost never have to use `new` in modern C++. 2) Use `gdb` to see where exactly the segfault is happening.

Comment: With `char * parsed[100]` you have 100 pointers to `char *`, but they do not point at allocated space...

Comment: without using char*parsed[100] iam not able to copy my tokens into parsed. i have tried every function strcpy, strncpy nothing is working.

Comment: @QandeelMushtaq It is because you allocate no memory anywhere. Just as you used `new[]` for `input`, you need to use it for every single array in that array of pointers. And don't forget to `delete[]` them when done, otherwise you create memory leaks.

Comment: I always wonder why beginners find "writing your own shell" so fascinating a project to practice on. Between bad tokenizing and the inevitable call to `system()`, it usually results in pretty dismal code and lots of frustration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize the variable `count`, and its value is undefined(may be very large, so the program will fail reading from memory). You should use `int count = 0;`.

And the elements in the array `parsed` isn't initialized and does not point to allocated memory. The behavior of your call to `strcpy` is also undefined. Add `parsed[count] = new char[strlen(token) + 1];` before your call to `strcpy`. Don't forget to use `delete` after everything is done.

At last, I think you didn't use `strtok` properly. Why did you use `&(token[count])`? Maybe you should replace it with `token`.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <string.h>
```

No.

If you want the C functions, use `<cstring>`, which puts them in the `std::` namespace.

But you don't *want* the C functions, you want C++ `<string>`. Believe me, you do.

```
using namespace std;
```

I'll let that pass for the example's sake. Get out of that particular habit in any production code.

```
    getline(cin,insert);
```

Good. You're ready to do C++.

```
    input= new char [insert.size()+1];
    strcpy(input, insert.c_str());
```

Bad. You just tied your hands to your back.

```
    char * parsed[100];
```

An array of 100 pointers to char. Just the pointers, uninitialized, pointing nowhere.

```
    int count;
```

Uninitialized.

```
    token=strtok(input, " ");
```

C. *shudder*....

```
        strcpy(parsed[count],&(token[count]));
```

**Undefined behaviour. `count` is not initialized, and even if it *does* happen to be between 0 and 99, `parsed[count]` still does not point to valid memory, so copying something to it *will* do bad things.**

Besides, your token is at `token`, not at `token[count]`...

```
        count++;
```

Adding 1 to uninitialized is UB, and still uninitialized. ;-)

```
}
```

You forgot to `delete [] input`.

---

Let me suggest a different, more C++-ish approach, that will still give you your array of pointers to each token (if you insist on that):

```
getline( cin, input );

// turn spaces to null bytes
std::replace( input.begin(), input.end(), ' ', '\0' );

// need an additional one for the finds below to work
input.append( '\0' );

// vector takes away all of that manual memory management
std::vector< char * > parsed;

size_t i = 0;

// skip leading (ex-) spaces
while ( ( i = input.find_first_not_of( '\0', i ) ) != std::string::npos )
{
    // push the pointer to the token on the vector
    parsed.push_back( input.data() + i );

    // skip to end of token
    i = input.find( '\0', i );
}
```

At this point, `parsed` is a `vector` of `char *` to the tokens in `input` (at least, as long as `input` itself is still in scope). You can check its size with `parsed.size()`, and access it as "naked" array with `parsed.data()`, although I am sure you will find the `vector` more convenient.

If you don't want to keep `input` around, replace

```
std::vector< char * > parsed;
```

with

```
std::vector< std::string > parsed;
```

and

```
parsed.push_back( input.data() + i );
```

with

```
parsed.push_back( std::string( input.data() + i ) );
```

and you have a *copy* of the tokens in your `vector`.

That is still pretty rough handling, mind you, since even spaces inside of quotation marks will be detected as "end of token", but at least it's C++, none of that C string handling.

Answer (score 1):

Variable int count is undefined, in means it can be random value, change it to int count = 0;

Comment: That's one of several problems.

Comment: i have initialized it. Still problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize your count variable to 0

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try to use this code. I tried in VS2010 and it is working fine now.

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    char* input = NULL;
    string insert;
    cout<<"My Shell $";

   /* getline(cin, insert);*/
    std::getline(cin, insert);
    input= new char[insert.size() + 1];
    strcpy(input, insert.c_str());

    char* token = NULL;
    char* parsed[100] = {0};

    int count = 0;

    token = strtok(input, " ");

    while ( token != NULL)
    {
        parsed[count] = token;
        count++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    for ( int index = 0; index<count; index++ )
    {
        cout << parsed[index] << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below code #

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    char* input = NULL;
    string insert;
    cout<<"My Shell $";

    getline(cin, insert);
    input= new char[insert.size() + 1];
    strcpy(input, insert.c_str());

    char* token = NULL;
    char* parsed[100];

    for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++)
    {
        parsed[index] = NULL;
    }

    int count = 0;

    token = strtok(input, " ");

    while ( token != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(parsed[count], &(token[count]));
        count++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char * parsed[100] = {0};` does the same as your loop. And instead of copying tokens to unspecified locations, you're now copying them to the null pointer. Actually you're not copying tokens, since `token[count]` is wrong as well. You fixed but one mistake of many.